# Printer not printing, ejects a blank page

Tags: printing, google-chrome, libreoffice, pdf, canon

3 days ago, I needed to print a page from Chrome, print job doesn't happen, so I copied what I needed from the browser, pasted and saved in Libre Office, on printing it ejected a blank page. So I then used saved as a PDF and the page printed.

Today, nothing is printing, just blank page after blank page and yes, the inks are @ 100% full as they are all new cartridges (in the last month) and no I haven't used them all up because cartridges don't run out after printing 5 pages.

- Printer: Epson D92
- Ubuntu: 14.10

Printer working fine and come to use today and nothing other than blank pages.

Suggestions on what to check, anything?

Also note that UNTIY does not show any programs other than what is pinned to the side bar thingy, which is utterly annoying where it is...

So can people advise on how to poke this distro via the terminal please.

Comment: Problem is in Chrome, I work for a copier company and for a week now we have been getting lots of calls with this issue, the only app this happens in is Chrome all other apps print with no issues. Have not been able to find a resolution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling the printer from the System Settings > Printers menu. Check the driver you are using on it, and send a test page to print. Also, try to print something from the Document Viewer and not from the Google Chrome, sometimes the problem is with the browser printing.

Comment: Ok, but to note that I did nothing but plug the printer in and it worked from day one. The Document viewer was the default PDF reader on my install. Yep, google, system, copy & paste, rewite by pasting in to new document and export to PDF, tried local Libre Office format to print from as well.  Can't think what else to do.